# Android open Dialog animation listener

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I have Dialog that has EditText. this dialog has enter and exist animation that defined in style.xml

```
<style name="LocationDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/LocationDialogAnimation</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LocationDialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialog_location_enter_anim</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialog_location_exit_anim</item>
    </style>
```

i want to open the keyboard after enter animation finished cause my current solution

```
locationDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

overlap the animation and doesn't wait for the animation to finish first.

i also tried

```
locationDialog.setOnShowListener(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be possible by using Animation in code. You can first set the focus  of your EditText to android:focusable="false" in xml or in code and when your enter animation finished you can the requestFocus to true.

```
Animation enter= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.enter_anim);
enter.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
          yourEditText.setFocusable(true);
          yourEditText.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

I hope it will help you.